# Jackson deserialization with multiple naming strategies

Tags: jackson, rabbitmq, deserialization

I would like my Jackson de-serialization process (while consuming from a Rabbit queue) to support both Snake and Camel case, depending on the messages representing the same object.

This might look weird... So this would be temporary, in order to workaround publisher and consumer services release complexity due to this format change.

Is there an easy way to that with Jackson?

Comment: It could be possible if you had for example a json field indicating which one strategy you would apply and two different `ObjectMapper` mappers for the deserialization.

Comment: You can create an abstraction for deserialisation process, for example using [Chain of Responsibility](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/chain-of-responsibility) pattern and create two or more mappers. First one which successfully parses event should return an object. Remember to enable [FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES) feature which will not allow to skip unknown properties.